# Semantic UI dropdown doesn't refresh from changed select childElement

Tags: javascript, dropdown, semantic-ui

If I initialize a dropdown with a select element, and then change that element, calling 'refresh' on the dropdown only half works:

```
<select id=one class="ui dropdown">
  <option value="a">A</option>
  <option value="b">B</option>
  <option value="c">C</option>
</select>

<select id=two>
  <option value="x">X</option>
  <option value="y">Y</option>
  <option value="z">Z</option>
</select>

$('.ui.dropdown').dropdown();

//I have templated lists that get swapped in and out
var one = document.getElementById("one");
var two = document.getElementById("two");
one.innerHTML = two.innerHTML;

$('.ui.dropdown').dropdown('refresh');
$('.ui.dropdown').dropdown('set selected', 'x');  //this doesn't work
```

After swapping the options, the dropdown correctly displays the second list.  I can also select them manually.   However, the 'set selected' function acts as if those options aren't there.

I've read about how 'refresh' looks for new '' elements and not new '' elements.   However I don't have any '' elements to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

I experienced this issue in a React component that used Semantic UI's dropdown.

It's not the most cost efficient way of resolving this, but I prefer just destroying the dropdown and recreating it when I know that the dynamic data is actually going to change, it seems much cleaner than fiddling with async checks:

```
$('#my_dropdown').dropdown('destroy');
$('#my_dropdown').dropdown({fullTextSearch: true});
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are talking the same problem here [github issue2247](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/2247).
That makes two of us. It seems that this "refresh" operation is an async one, so setting selected value for your dropdown right after refresh won't work, at least for now - there is no solution given on this official issue. you may use setTimeout to wait for you refresh operation to complete, but it's not perfect, bothering me a lot too.

Answer (score 0):

As @lisnb has said in the previous answer, setTimeout is a hack that can solve your problems for dynamically added options and is used like this:

```
setTimeout(function () {  
   $(id).dropdown('set selected', value);
}, 1);
```

However, if you are initializing the dropdown on `<div>` element instead of `<select>` this is not enough and you have to manually set both the value and the element shown as selected:

```
$(id).dropdown('set value', value)
setTimeout(function () {  
    $(id).dropdown('set selected', value);
}, 1);
```

Imho, dropdown functionality (especially when adding options dynamically) is one of the weak spots of Semantic UI and should be used with care.